# Extract mail header and decode MIME encoded-word

Tags: email, unicode

As part of a script, I want to take a file containing an email and extract a header, e.g., the subject header. The following almost works:

```
formail -c -x subject < FILE
```

But it does not decode headers encoded using the MIME encoded-word syntax (aka RFC2047), e.g., `=?UTF-8?B?w6lsw6ltZW50?=`.

What's a nice way to extract an email header while taking care of decoding MIME encoded-word parts?

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457380/retrieve-email-subject-from-file-via-bash

Comment: Maybe `munpack` can help. https://linux.die.net/man/1/munpack

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure? `munpack` seems to be about decoding MIME parts of messages, not headers.

Comment: I am not sure, but it is worth trying.

Comment: Sure, but trying what? I looked at the man, nothing seems relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pipe it to:

**python**)

```
formail -c -x Subject < FILE | \
python -c "from email.header import decode_header;
import sys;
text, encoding = decode_header(sys.stdin.read())[0];
print text.decode(encoding)"
```

**php**)

```
formail -c -x Subject < FILE | \
  php -r 'echo iconv_mime_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN),1,"utf-8");'
```

or if you're sure that the header will be `=?UTF-8?B?…` then you can easily do:

```
formail -c -x Subject < FILE | \
  awk -F '[?]' '{print $4}' | \
  openssl enc -base64 -d -A
```

python should be probably most universal, since it is in probably all systems by default and even the email module is present.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903893/python-imap-utf-8q-in-subject-string